# how to remove from price value and to price value in magento

Tags: product, magento-1, price, bundled-product

- From: $xxxx.00
- To: $xxxx.00

PRICE AS CONFIGURED: $xxxx.00

I want to remove it from bundle product.[image]

Comment: Edit `app\design\fronted\<your namespace>\<your theme>\template\bundle\catalog\product\price.phtml` and search for `<p class="price-to">` and delete everything up to the next `</p>` tag.

Comment: i want to show only  max  price value  from price column .where  from and to price written. please tell me how i can show it???

Answer (score 1):

Edit `app\design\fronted\<your namespace>\<your theme>\template\bundle\catalog\product\price.phtml` and search for `<p class="price-from">` and delete everything up to the next `</p>` tag. Alternatively in css you can just hide the class `.price-from`